# É possível inserir novo HTML com pure.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou querendo usar o pure.js framework, para criar um post via json.

Encontrei na plataforma da Stack em inglês [esse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608602/is-it-possible-to-insert-new-html-with-pure-js/14399899#14399899), que é o que eu quero fazer, só que tem uma problema, não estou conseguindo fazer o exemplo da segunda pessoa que respondeu embaixo.

Arturo Hernandez;

No seu exemplo, seu modelo HTML deve ser assim:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="/img/pappo.gif" />
    <h1>marte</h1>
    <p><a href="http:://www.sito.it>guille</a></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

e um json gosta disso:

```
{
   "mylist":{
      "listone": 
          {"img" : "/img/pippo1.gif" ,
           "text1" : "pluto1",
           "text2" : "topolino1",
           "link" : "http://www.sito1.it"       
           },
      "listtwo":
          {"img" : "/img/pippo2.gif" ,
           "text1" : "pluto2",
           "text2" : "topolino2",
           "link" : "http://www.sito2.it"       
          }
   }
}
```

e a final deve ser assim:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="/img/pippo1.gif" />
    <h1>pluto1</h1>
    <p><a href="http:://www.sito1.it>topolino1</a></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="/img/pippo2.gif" />
    <h1>pluto2</h1>
    <p><a href="http:://www.sito2.it>topolino2</a></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

O primeiro eu conseguir fazer de boa, agora esse segundo de dois, eu não conseguir.

Como seria o código em javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tiver uma lista de objetos fica mais fácil, pois assim você poderá percorrer a lista e associar os valores de cada respectivo objeto a injeção html que deseja fazer. Aliás, você pode fazer injeção de html sem nenhum framework.

Um exemplo de lista de objetos:

```
    { 
      listaObj : [
        {
          nome : "Testador",
          idade : 25,
          sexo : "M"
        },{
          nome : "Testadora",
          idade : 22,
          sexo : "F"
        }
     ]
   }
```

Desta forma você percorre a lista olhando os objetos de forma mais dinâmica somente utilizando seus atributos e podes fazer a injeção de html. Segue um exemplo utilizando a lista de objetos acima.

```
var divCentral = document.getElementById("central");
for(var i = 0; i < listaObj.length; i++){
  var divNome = document.createElement("div")
  divNome.innerHTML = listaObj[i].nome
  divCentral.appendChild(divNome)
}
```

Desta forma é indiferente o tamanho da lista dos seus objetos, o código sempre funcionará.

:)

Comment: Poderia fazer o exemplo acima no jsfiddle?, ai está apenas o demostração com o "nome".

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora! Posso sim, hoje mesmo lhe disponibilizo.

Comment: @MatheusCalixto Segue exemplo no fiddle, é bem básico mas é possível se basear nele, faça um teste aumentando a quantidade de objetos para ver como funciona. https://jsfiddle.net/tetbdkpe/

Comment: Obrigado Luan vou dar uma olhada;